# Problems with Hosting WCF service on IIS (Using WAS) for netTCP bindings?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, web, was

I created a simple WCF service and hosted it in IIS by creating a new website. In Web.config file,I am providing bindings for http and net tcp. 
I created a console client and adding service reference. It generates two binding in client config - for http and for tcp. When I try to invoke the service using tcp, I get this error -

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://computername/Service.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.**

when I run using Http endpoint , it works fine. 
Note -
I am using Windows 10 OS, IIS 10.0 and WPAS\WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) are installed. I already enabled\checked HTTP Activation, TCP Activation in .Net framework in Windows features. And modified IIS server settings to include net tcp. Please check it in attached image.
 [image]

My website Web.config file looks like

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0" portSharingEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None"  />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="My" name="WCFServiceOM.Service1"> <!--  the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFServiceOM.IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint  binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" contract="WCFServiceOM.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mexOM" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8087/Service1" />
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7777/Service1"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehanior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="My">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And my client App.Config look like

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>      
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService1">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://computername:7777/Service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://computername/Service.svc" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="NetTcpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```